# Inject a service to fill values in environment.ts file

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an `angular` service (`clientAppSettings.service.ts`). It gets the config values from backend which is a json File (`appsettings.json`)

I require to inject the angular service, to fill in the values in `environment.ts` file. So, the `instrumentaionKey` should be retrieved from service (clientAppSettings.service.ts). Any guide is appreciated.

Here is the `environmen.ts` file:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  appInsights: {
    instrumentationKey: 'some-key'
  } 
};
```

angular service: `clientAppSettings.service.ts` :

```
@Injectable()
export class ClientAppSettingService {
  appUrl: string = "";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    this.appUrl = baseUrl;
  }
  getConfig() {
    return this.http.get<ClientAppSettings>(this.appUrl + 'api/ClientAppSettings');
  }
}
```

backend controller:

```
namespace WebApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ClientAppSettingsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly AppSettings _clientAppSettings;

        public ClientAppSettingsController(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
        {
            _clientAppSettings = appSettings.Value;
        }

        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public AppSettings Get()
        {
            return _clientAppSettings;
        }
    }
}
```

and `appsetting.json`:

```
{
"AppConfig": {
        "ApplicationInsights": {
            "InstrumentationKey": "some-key"
        }
}
```

Comment: Im not sure you can do this. Perhaps use a token replace in an environment.ts file at buildtime in some CI process possibly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant update the env file in runtime, its something that angular use in build time. Just save the setting in your service and pull them from there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it like you explained (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2508). The environment files are used to set up some fixed variables for a specific environment.

If you want to store data from backend through your application you could use a shared service that holds the data.